# Is the use of the word "recognize" accurate in these sentences?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

The following are some learning outcomes a freshman student should achieve. Is the use of the word **recognize** accurate in these sentences? Or, is there a better way to say this?

1. **Recognize** the types of electric heating and Cooling systems.
2. **Recognize** the types of welding and electrolysis.
3. **Recognize** electrical laboratory devices.

EDIT:

This is actually a comment on the answer.

I mean, especially in the last sentence, that the students should be introduced to the devices and get to know them for the first time.
Isn't **get familiar with** an accurate alternative? Especially for non-abstract nouns like devices?

Comment: If your objective is recognition, then recognize is the right word.

Comment: There is a confusion with the word "recognition" itself. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Becoming familiar is related to recognition: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recognize At one level, you would test their familiarity with electrical laboratory devices by asking them to recognize them. At another level, you would test their familiarity with the devices by asking them to operate them.

Comment: So, the question again is which is better? and more accurate?

Comment: Looking in Oxford, I read the first definition: "Identify (someone or something) from having encountered them before; know again". In my question I say they get to know "for the first time".

Comment: It depends on your actual objective: visualizing your students showing you what they know at the end of your course, ***Recognize*** is pretty much limited to: This is a ___________. That is a ___________. These are ___________. They don't necessarily need to understand how anything works. Become familiar could substitute for recognize, but it suggests the possibility of being familiar with how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Be able to recognize..." seems to be what is meant by these statements, but it really depends on how this list is introduced.  For example, the list is fine as written if it's introduced by something like the following:

> At the end of this course, students will *be able to*:
>   [list]

But there, the "be able to" has been moved out to the intro.

In this context, **recognize** will probably be understood to mean (roughly) *"identify empirically based on comparison with examples seen (or heard/felt/smelled) in previous experience"*.

As far as a "better way to say this", it depends on what you're trying to say (see ScotM's comment on the original post).  If the students are going to be exposed to examples and taught distinguishing features of the various system types/welding & electrolysis/laboratory devices, then **recognize** is the right word for the job.